# How to pass json array of one page into another in php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

i have a `php` page `p1.php` where in a `JavaScript` function i have got some `json` `array` as `j` now i want to  use this `j` to another `php` page `p2.php`

i have tried it by

```
window.location.href="p2.php?data="+j
```

then in `p2.php` 
i used `$_get['data']` to get the result
but after researching i come to know the format is not good for huge data.
 so 
        i leave the idea of passing it into the `url`

Comment: you could use a POST request instead. If you're triggering that from JavaScript, you'll have to simultate submitting a form

Comment: can i send JSON data from form ?

Comment: You could always take it one step further and save the json into a database and access it on the next page then delete it from the database on the bottom of that page. Its clean and efficient.

Comment: Yes you could send in JSON format or you could send in form-url-encoded format (normal format for submitting form data). It doesn't really matter as long as the server knows what to expect.

Answer (score -1):

if your j is object then you can post with jquery

example :

```
$.post("p2.php", { datavar : j},function(data){
})
```

in your p2.php

```
print_r( $_POST["datavar"]);
echo $_POST["datavar"]["var2"];
```

Comment: would it be redirected to p2.php after post request

Comment: Based on the original code the OP wants to redirect to the new page, not just use Ajax. Also you cannot assume they're using (or willing to use) jQuery

Comment: @chenyu you can redirect manually after post  
 function(data){
  window.location = url
}

Comment: You could, but why make 2 HTTP requests when one will do the job? It's just wasteful. Ajax is unnecessary here

Answer (score -1):

it's depends of many data you can move, but always is ugly send pure data by url.
But in your example, only miss transform the json (object) to string:

```
window.location.href="p2.php?data="+JSON.stringify(j);
```

If you can go in the right way, store the info in a session:
http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

Then the p1.php looks like these:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['json'] = isset($_POST['json']) ? $_POST['json'] : null;
// other php stuffs
?>
<!-- other html stuffs -->
<script>
var json = { your: 'json' };
(function(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var data = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json));
  xhr.open('post', 'p1.php');
  xhr.send('json='+data);
})();
</script>
```

These code send the info (json) via AJAX to p1.php

Comment: Same as the other answer, Ajax is unnecessary here - the aim is to navigate to the second page as well, not just send the data